# Removing a string saved in a node from a list

Tags: c, list

I created this dynamic list where i can input a string, the string will be saved in a node of the list, `insert` is supposed to create the node, allocate the memory for the string and save it, while `delete` should receive as input one of the strings saved in the nodes, delete it and free the memory it was using. I'm having a lot of troubles with the delete function, it seems to receive the input but later it won't delete the node, it seems not to find the string to delete, in fact i only receive "not found" as output. I think that the error happens when i pass the string to remove to the function, but i can't find it, can anyone give me some advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// self-referential structure                       
struct listNode {                                      
   char *data; // each listNode contains a character 
   struct listNode *nextPtr; // pointer to next node
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode; // synonym for struct listNode
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; // synonym for ListNode*

// prototypes
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value);
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char  *value);
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr);
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr);
void instructions(void);
int main(void)
{ 
   ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL; // initially there are no nodes
   char item[20]; // char entered by user
   instructions(); // display the menu
   printf("%s", "? ");
   unsigned int choice; // user's choice
   scanf("%u", &choice);
   // loop while user does not choose 3
   while (choice != 3) { 
      switch (choice) { 
         case 1:
            printf("%s", "Enter a character: ");
            scanf("%s", item);
            insert(&startPtr, item); // insert item in list
            printList(startPtr);
            break;

     case 2: // delete an element
            // if list is not empty
            if (!isEmpty(startPtr)) { 
               printf("%s", "Enter character to be deleted: ");
               scanf("%s", item);
               // if character is found, remove it
               if (delete(&startPtr, item)) { // remove item
                  printf("%s deleted.\n", item);
                  printList(startPtr);
               } 
               else {
                  printf("%s not found.\n\n", item);
               } 
            } 
            else {
               puts("List is empty.\n");
            } 
            break;

         default:
            puts("Invalid choice.\n");
            instructions();
            break;
      } // end switch
      printf("%s", "? ");
      scanf("%u", &choice);
   } 
   puts("End of run.");
} 
// display program instructions to user
void instructions(void)
{ 
   puts("Enter your choice:\n"
      "   1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
      "   2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
      "   3 to end.");
}

// insert a new value into the list in sorted order
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value)
{ 
   ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create node

   if (newPtr != NULL) { // is space available
      newPtr->data= malloc(strlen(value)+1);
      strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
      newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; // node does not link to another node
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list       
      while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data) {
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...               
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node 
      }                                          
      // insert new node at beginning of list
      if (previousPtr == NULL) { 
         newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
         *sPtr = newPtr;
      } 
      else { // insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
         previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
         newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
      } 
   } 
   else {
      printf("%s not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
   } 
} 

// delete a list element
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value)
{ 
   // delete first node if a match is found
   if (value == (*sPtr)->data) { 
      ListNodePtr tempPtr = *sPtr; // hold onto node being removed
      *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr; // de-thread the node
      free(tempPtr); // free the de-threaded node
      return *value;
   } 
   else { 
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = *sPtr;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value) { 
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...  
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node  
      } 
      // delete node at currentPtr
      if (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         ListNodePtr tempPtr = currentPtr;
         previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
         free(tempPtr);
         return *value;
      } 
   } 
   return '\0';
} 

// return 1 if the list is empty, 0 otherwise
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{ 
   return sPtr == NULL;
} 


// print the list
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr)
{ 
   // if list is empty
   if (isEmpty(currentPtr)) {
      puts("List is empty.\n");
   } 
   else { 
      puts("The list is:");
      // while not the end of the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         printf("%s --> ", currentPtr->data);
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;   
      } 
      puts("NULL\n");
   } 
}
```

Comment: This might be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `char []` a character array to store string 
if you are doing this for comparing values

> value == (*sPtr)->data

then you are only comparing pointer address of those ptrs.

You need to compare values so you have to use `strcmp` function to compare **c style string**

> strcmp(value,(*sPtr)->data)==0

```
 char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value)
{ 
   // delete first node if a match is found
   if (strcmp(value,(*sPtr)->data)==0) {              //like this
      ListNodePtr tempPtr = *sPtr; // hold onto node being removed
      *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr; // de-thread the node
      free(tempPtr); // free the de-threaded node
      return *value;
   } 
   else { 
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = *sPtr;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(currentPtr->data,value)!=0) { 
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...  
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node  
      } 
      // delete node at currentPtr
      if (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         ListNodePtr tempPtr = currentPtr;
         previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
         free(tempPtr);
         return *value;
      } 
   } 
   return '\0';
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you a lot @onk_r ! Thanks!

Comment: I accepted it! Sorry, i wasn't able to accept it from the start because i had to wait 6 minutes!